# Possible to create random slope model with fixed intercept in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I'm  aware that it's pretty unusual to assume random slopes but fixed intercepts, and that it is not ideal for me to be using SPSS for this task. However, I'm doing this analysis in a teaching context in which I have no other choice.

I attempted to make this happen by leaving Include intercept unchecked but this didn't work - I ended up with a model where the intercepts were all different and the slopes were zero.

[image]

In response to Jeremy's comment I took a look at the syntax.

MIXED jobsat WITH physen
  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, 
    ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=physen | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=REML
  /PRINT=COVB  SOLUTION TESTCOV
  /RANDOM=physen | SUBJECT(grpid) COVTYPE(VC)
  /SAVE=PRED.

There doesn't seem to be any reference here to the intercept being fixed. I amended the fourth line of syntax so it read

/FIXED=INTERCEPT physen | SSTYPE(3)

but that still produced a model where the intercept was not fixed.

Comment: Have you tried using syntax?

Comment: Can you give a little more context as to what you're trying to do? Are you sure you need to be using the linear mixed model procedure?

Comment: @jeremy-miles I was not familiar with the syntax but have pasted it above, along with one attempt I have tried which did not work. Do you have any suggestions for how I might proceed?

Comment: @DocBuckets It's a teaching example. In SPSS I've shown my students a model with random intercepts and fixed slope, and an example with random intercepts and random slopes. I'd like to complete the set by showing a model with a fixed intercept but random slopes.

Comment: I haven't used SPSS mixed models for a while, I thought it might say random=intercept physen, but it doesn't. I wonder if you can set element 1, 1 of the covariance matrix to zero with the covtype option. Sorry, I don't know a way.

Comment: The command syntax reference states there is a `NOINT` option on the fixed subcommand. So it appears if you replace `INTERCEPT` with `NOINT` it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing it to  `/FIXED=[name of my predictor variable] | SSTYPE(3) NOINT` but unfortunately that didn't work either.